# How to print numbers side by side on the same line using different threads in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is what the output should look like:

[image]

Each column should be printed using a separate thread. So in this case there will be 3 threads, one that prints the numbers, an other that prints their squares and an other that prints their cubes.

Following everyone's comments i have written this code.

```
public class PrintThread
{
private static final int LIMIT=10;
final static Queue<Integer> number=new LinkedList();
final static Queue<Integer> square=new LinkedList();
final static Queue<Integer> cube=new LinkedList();        
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Number\tSquare\tCube");
    for(int i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
        number.offer(i);
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
                square.offer(i*i);
        }
    }).start();
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<LIMIT;i++)
                cube.offer(i*i*i);
        }
    }).start();
    for(int i=0;i<LIMIT;i++){        
        System.out.println(number.poll()+"\t"+square.poll()+"\t"+cube.poll());
    }
}    
}
```

Now this still does not ensure the correct output.
I want the main thread to print only after the other two threads have finished filling the queues. How do I do that?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. You're asking how to do something, but then you describe precisely how to do it. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Do you need each thread to print its own column? There'll be a ton of ugly synchronization you could avoid with a different design, perhaps having 3 threads feed queues that a dedicated output thread polls for numbers to print.

Comment: Is it possible to fill some data structure with the threads and when the process is finished print it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn’t show a good faith attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @Arkanon Yes i want it on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Actually 3 thread **printing** on the same line one after another conveys the meaning of sequential execution. I do not think threads are useful here.

But if you mean only **Calculation** needs to be done using different threads, then you can use `join()` on the threads. You can use one loop to initialize and start the threads and in the second loop `join()` them. (Note that if you `join()` in the same loop, then the threads execute as sequentially.)

After the second loop you can print the formatted result.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
        class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
        private Thread t;
        private String threadName;
        static   int i=0;
        RunnableDemo( String name){

             threadName = name;
       }
       public void run() {
       i=i+1;
       System.out.print(""+i+"\t\t"+(i*i)+"\t");
       }

       public void start ()
        {
         System.out.print("\t"+(i*i*i+"\n"));
        }
       }

      class TestThread {
      public static void main(String args[]) 
      {

    System.out.print("Number Square Cube\n");  
    RunnableDemo [] r1=new RunnableDemo[10]; 

        for(int i=1;i<10;i++)
        {
            r1[i]=new RunnableDemo(""+i);
            r1[i].run();
            r1[i].start();
          }
      }   
 }
```

[image]